# Initialize tuple across inheritance tree

Tags: c++, inheritance, tuples

Let class B be the base of A:

```
class B
{
public:
    std::tuple<int, bool, float> properties.
}

class A : public B
{
public:
    std::tuple<float, std::string, std::string> derivedProperties.
}
```

Is there some way to add the derived properties tuple to the base propeties tuple? For example through some form of CRTP? I know that the properties of the base class and the derived types are known at compile time, but I can't seem to figure out how to combine the properties of the different inheritance levels.

Comment: As for your problem, you might be interested in learning about [*template parameter packs*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Comment: But how would I use a variadic template constructor to determine the type of a base member tuple?

Comment: Is the tuple in `B` supposed to always have at least the types you show? And you want to add more fields (so the resulting `properties` tuple would be `std::tuple<int, bool, float, float, std::string, std::string>`?

Comment: Also, have you considered using a *`struct`* instead of a tuple? Because then the derived class `A` could have its own `struct` that inherits from the base class.

Comment: Yes exactly to the outside world I would like the tuple in class B to have all the property types.

Comment: Lastly, what is the *actual* problem you want to solve with this? Why do you need this tuple and "extend" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it when you thought about CRTP.

You could do the following:

```
// We need this boilerplate to overcome
// the incompleteness of "Derived" when instantiating "Base<Derived>"
template <typename T>
struct properties {
    using type = std::tuple<>;
};

class Derived;

template <>
struct properties<Derived> {
    using type = std::tuple<float, std::string, std::string>;
};

// Now that we defined our properties
template <typename Derived>
class Base {
public:
    using derived_properties_t = typename properties<Derived>::type; // Should be a tuple
    using base_properties_t = std::tuple<int, bool, float>;
    using combined_properties_t = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<base_properties_t>(),
                                                          std::declval<derived_properties_t>()));
    combined_properties_t properties;
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
public:
    using properties_type = std::tuple<float, std::string, std::string>;
};
```

You can see a working demo on [<kbd>Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a5d28690c23f39c)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [variadic templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) to add more types to the `properties` member of your base class (`B`). If you wish to have constructors of base class in derived class too, you can use the [using-declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration):

```
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

template<typename... Ts>
class B {
public:
    B(int i, bool b, float f, const Ts&... rest) :
            properties(std::make_tuple(i, b, f, rest...)) {
    }
    std::tuple<int, bool, float, Ts...> properties;
};

class A : public B<float, std::string, std::string> {
    using B::B;
};

int main() {
    A foo(12, true, 3.14, 6.28, "foo", "bar");
}
```

---

Passing derived classes of `class B` to the same function can be achieved through function templates:

```
template<typename... Ts>
void test(const B<Ts...>& base);
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/Syr7LJ)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You might use the following if relevant:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
class C
{
public:
    std::tuple<int, bool, float, Ts...> properties.
};

using B = C<>;
using A = C<float, std::string, std::string>;
```